# What is the significance of closure property on a set and a binary operator?

Tags: abstract-algebra

A group is defined as a set with a binary operation define on it, which satisfies closure, associative, identity and inverse properties. Why is closure property included in the definition what is the significance of this property?

Comment: To guarantee that the product of two elements remains in the group.

Comment: If you did not have closure, where would this operation "live"? In fact, it is not an operation at all if it does not satisfy closure, which is why this is often left out in the definition of a group.

Comment: Pardon me if this is a stupid question, isn't an operation same as a function that can be define from one set to another set. Cant we say that this binary operation is a function acting on two input elements from a set and the result will be in another set.

Comment: We could, but it just happens that we do not. A binary operation os a set $X$ is by definition a map from $X\times X$ to $X$.

Comment: Thanks Tobias! Can you explain what is the role of associative property.